# Android 2.1 switch loop JRE 1.7

Tags: android

Hello how to use switch loop in my android project ? I want to use Android 2.1

I need JRE 1.7, but I want to use Android 2.1

I use loop like this:

```
switch ((CHAR[Math.abs(intGen.nextInt()%2)])) {
    case "+":
        result = random2 + random3;
        break;
    case "-":
        result = random2 + random3;
        break;
}
```

LogCat:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put: there is no way to do it right now, Android SDK is not the Oracle JDK. Not all features are supported, and AFAIK `String` support for switch statements is not among the supported ones.

I'm afraid you're stuck using the good old `equals`:

```
if(myString.equals("+")){
 result = random2 + random3;
}
else if (myString.equals("-"))
 result = random2 - random3;
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. android is jre6 only. you need to do this some other way. An easy way would be to have CHAR be actually chars, that are switchable.

Comment: given that CHAR is compared to 1-char strings, are you sure you cannot declare CHAR as a char[] rather than a String[] ?

Answer (score 0):

Stucked in the same problem, changing switch-case to if-else solved the problem.
Switch-case before java 1.7 supports primitive types(boolean, char, short, byte, int) & enums, switching on Strings is introduced in java 1.7. Another way can be to change switch(String) to switch(int).